# php mysql fetch array and loop rows

Tags: php, arrays, variables, mysqli, while-loop

i have a database table 'movies'. in this table there are 25 columns of information per row. Ie, movie title, poster, cast, synopsis etc.

At the moment i am fetching the information like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `movies` WHERE `title`='$moviename'";

$result = $con->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);


if($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$moviedetails['title']=$row['title'];
$moviedetails['poster']=$row['poster']; 
}
}
else {
echo 'NO RESULTS';  
}
```

because i have 25 columns its long work writing out each variable. is there a way to fetch the information and i can then call to it by using

```
$moviedetails['column name']
```

ie

im new to php and mysql so any help appreciated.

thanks
lee

```
$moviedetails['title']
```

fetches the information from the 'title' column.

Comment: once i wrote 50 columns manually.. :) by the way you can put all the columns data in array at a time by `$moviedetails[]=$row;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 foreach ($row as $key => $value){
 $moviedetails[$key]=$value;
 }
 }
```

This input the same key and the same value into new array

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `movies` WHERE `title`='$moviename'";

$result = $con->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($moviedetails = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //just use moviedetails for what you need
    }
} else {
    echo 'NO RESULTS';  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while($moviedetails[]=$result->fetch_assoc()){}
```

then you loop by it like this:

```
foreach($moviedetails as $num->row)
{
    echo $row['title'];
}
```